# How to hide the menu when using multiple select in GridView in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview, android-menu

I use GridView and implement multiple select.

When I select the multiple item from GridView , it will show the menu on the top of screen.

But I don't want the menu show on the top .

I set the `GridView` to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` and implement thr `MultiChoiceModeListener` of class.

Does there has any method can hide the menu when select the multiple item ?

The code of class is like the following

```
public class LocalFileBrowserFragment extends Fragment implements MultiChoiceModeListener
```

The code of setup the `GridView` is like the following:

```
private GridView fileListView;
fileListView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.browserList) ;
fileListView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
fileListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener((MultiChoiceModeListener)this);
fileListView.setNumColumns(4);
```

And the code of `MultiChoiceModeListener` in `GridView` is like the following:

```
@Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateActionMode");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < fileListView.getCount(); i++) {
            fileListView.setItemChecked(i, false);
            mSelectMap.clear();
        }
        mFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.i(TAG, "onPrepareActionMode");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
            long id, boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mSelectMap.put(position, checked);
        mFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I set the `GridView` to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` and implement thr `MultiChoiceModeListener` of class.

I don't want the menu show on the top.

Does there has any method can hide the menu when select the multiple item ?

Comment: how about CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE instead of CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL?

Comment: And maybe your onCreateActionMode() has to return false to prevent the action mode to be created?

Comment: I have try , but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I used  the following to show the bar.

```
bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
bar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save ActionMode as a field of your MultiChoiceModeListener in onCreateActionMode

```
       @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            theActionMode = mode;
            return true;
        }
```

Then finish the ActionMode in onItemCheckedStateChanged

```
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

        // Your CheckedChange Code......

        theActionMode.finish();
    }
```